Import classes from another package

I'm trying to run the mainApi.py, but I'm always getting an error of ModuleNotFoundError, both for the class aws_photo and printerWindows.
I'm importing them in this way:
from printer.printerWindows import printerWindows
from aws_classes.aws_photo import aws_photo

I run the code with the command: python -m api.mainApi, but if I try to run it with the command python mainApi.py it doesn't work.
How should I fix it?

It seems you already know how to fix it, use python -m api.mainApi. You could also change the directory in your terminal one level up and use python api/mainApi.py, however this will not work anymore if you start using relative imports in mainApi.py.

tryfrom aws_classes import aws_photo and same thing for printer. you've already imported the module with from and there are no modules in them

if you have all code in folder /full/path/to/project (so you have subfolders /full/path/to/project/aws_classes, /full/path/to/project/printer, etc) then you may have to add this folder to sys.path before import - sys.path.append("/full/path/to/project") - and when you use import aws_classes (or similars) then it will use "/full/path/to/project/" + "aws_classes" to load code . BTW: and you may have to add  (empty) file__init__.py in folder aws_classes and printer (and others)

to make sure: you have to add "/full/path/to/project" to sys.path, not "/full/path/to/project/aws_classes"

other idea: put folder aws_classes and printer inside folder api - to have api/aws_classes and api/printer and code inside api/mainApi.py should find it without using sys.path. But still it may need to add __init__.py in subfolders.
